# Trigger an event when user clicks on a divs horizontal scrollbar arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a div with a horizontal scroll.

[image]

- Is there any way I can detect the click on the horizontal scrolls
  arrow using jQuery ?

> **Note:**

Actually I want the scroll to move a fixed no of pixels to the right when the user clicks the right scroll arrow and vice versa.

> The event should not be triggered on scroll. It should be only   triggered if user explicitly clicks the scrolls arrow.
>
> There are multiple divs having scrollbars, having same class and no ids.
>
> Would prefer to not use any plugins

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo for what you want

http://jsbin.com/opufow/4/edit

I hope this will help you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use .scroll function of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2**: Another suggestion is to do *something like this* depending on your implementation of scrolling areas (see [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7tsT/1/)):

```
function CustomScrollArrow(elementToScroll) {
    var $el = $(elementToScroll);
    return $('<a>Click me to scroll</a>').css(/*...*/).click(function(){
        $el.scrollLeft($el.scrollLeft()+10);
    });
}

$('.ScrollAreaClass').each(function(){
    // You could choose to append to your scrolling
    // areas or their wrapper classes or whatever...
    $('body').append(new CustomScrollArrow(this));
});​
```

Afterwards it's just a matter of styling your handmade arrows.

**Edit 1**: I've seen you updated your question, so here's an updated answer with an alternative solution.

You can try to circumvent the problem by using a customized scrollbars implementation, for example [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) by Kelvin Luck or any other, whatever. If the solution offers click events on arrows - then you're set. Otherwise just do a bit of tinkering...

I maintain, however, my point of view that unless you are looking to perform an action **before** the browser executes the arrow click, I would recommend adding an event handler to the actual result of that click, i.e. the scroll.

Doing this will help to avoid inconsistencies across various implementations of scrolling in browsers; will keep working if scrolling is performed in another manner (i.e. swipe gesture); will still work if there's some javascript code that replaces the default browser implementation of scrollbars.

jQuery offers the [.scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) handler to capture scrolling and [.scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) to determine the resulting position of the horizontally scrolled content.

Try a **[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maAGz/2/)** or see the code below:

```
// Cache the initial scroll position:
var initialLeftScroll = $('#wrapper').scrollLeft();
// Bind event:
$('#wrapper').scroll(function (ev) { 
    // Get new horizontal scroll offset:
    var currentLeftScroll = $('#wrapper').scrollLeft();
    // Determine the difference
    // (did the user scroll horizontally or just vertically?):
    var leftScrollDifference = currentLeftScroll - initialLeftScroll;
    // Now we can check 
    if (leftScrollDifference) {
        /* Do something here */
    }
    // Reset the cache:
    initialLeftScroll = currentLeftScroll;
});
```

Comment: Actually i want the scroll to move a fixed no of pixels to the right when the user clicks the right scroll arrow & vice versa..

Comment: When I saw this example, I got an idea: You could maybe check if the difference is exactly 40 or -40, and then excecute the event if that's true. It should be quite safe, however I guess that's different on different systems.

Comment: yes, even i thought the same.. but since the div does not have id in my case I am not able to grab the initial value/pos of the scroll..

Comment: @Ineentho I'm not sure that all browsers behave and will behave in the same way, consistently adding/removing 40px. I would advise against this.

Comment: @PriyankKapasi Ah, in this case what you could do is to hide the scrolling completely with overflow-x:hidden; and implement a custom-styled element that would be a child of the scrolling area and exhibit the following behavior: `onclick="$(this).parent().scrollLeft(40);"`. Thus you don't need to know any id(s) and your behavior will be 100% consistent with any browser supported by jQuery.

Comment: @Oleg Yes, that could be done.. But i am curious to know about a solution without any work around ;-)